# "How to skip a line between strings in R?"

Tags: r

I'm doing a swirl lesson.
This is the problem:
Edit the string inside writeLines() so that it correctly displays
 (with the line breaks in these positions)

```
 This is a really

 really really

 long string
```

I tried typing

```
writeLines("This is a really\n\nreally really\n\nlong string")
```

but the swirl lesson keeps telling me that it is incorrect. Is there a different way to write the same thing?

Comment: try `cat` instead of `writeLines`

Comment: That seems to produce the output you've shown above. Are you sure that's what the question is after? It's hard for us to guess what swirl might think is the correct answer.

Comment: What's the chance you need to double-escape the `n`s (i.e., `\\n`)? I'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

Swirl is generally very strict about the answer, as it would be time consuming and difficult to put in ways to check for all the potentially correct answers.

As a matter of fact the answer is `writelines("This is a really \nreally really \nlong string")` (see [here](https://github.com/j2hoon85/e_learning/blob/master/DataCamp/step_2.%20Data%20Wrangling/Data%20Manipulation/Course_String%20Manipulation%20in%20R%20with%20stringr/Chapter%201.%20String%20basics%20(1).txt)). You have the newline `\n` doubled, so `Swirl` won't accept that as an answer.